# get a specific value within a html tag in a file

Tags: xml, jenkins

i have a text file with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <slave> <name>slave1</name> <description>00.000.000.00</description> <remoteFS>/home/<dir>/</remoteFS> <numExecutors>8</numExecutors> <mode>NORMAL</mode> <retentionStrategy class="hudson.slaves.RetentionStrategy$Always"/> <launcher class="hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher" plugin="ssh-slaves@1.25.1"> <host>00.000.000.00</host> <port>9192</port> <credentialsId>xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx</credentialsId> <javaPath>/usr/bin/java</javaPath> <maxNumRetries>0</maxNumRetries> <retryWaitTime>0</retryWaitTime> <sshHostKeyVerificationStrategy class="hudson.plugins.sshslaves.verifiers.NonVerifyingKeyVerificationStrategy`"/> </launcher> <label>xxxxx</label> <nodeProperties> <hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty> <envVars serialization="custom"> <unserializable-parents/> <tree-map> <default> <comparator class="hudson.util.CaseInsensitiveComparator"/> </default> <int>4</int> <string>CTS_HOME</string> <string>xxxx</string> <string>xxxxx</string> <string>xxxxx</string> <string>PYTHONPATH</string> <string>/home/<dir></string></tree-map> </envVars> </hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty> </nodeProperties> </slave>`
```

i want the value `<launcher class="hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher"` from this whole file, but i am unable to get this value
Also `hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher`value is different for different launch method the jenkins slave uses

How can i get only the launcher class value?
Here is what i have tried so far,

```
cat text_file | sed -nr 's/.*launcher="([^"]+)".*/\1/p'
cat text_file | sed -n 's:.*<launcher>\(.*\)</launcher>.*:\1:p'
cat text_file | grep -o '<launcher>.*</launcher>'
```

but none of these 3 work.
can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is :

```
sed -n 's:.*<launcher class="\(.*\)" plugin=".*">.*</launcher>.*:\1:p' text_file
```

It should output :

```
hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher
```

Comment: no i can get the other details...i just need this value SSHLauncher from the file....the value of launcher class field from the file

Comment: Please explain what output you want

Comment: i just want this value ""hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher" from the text file..i have a lot of text files whih have different values from launcher class...so i just need the value of the launcher class...which is hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher in this particular case

Comment: Nice to hear. If it solves your problem don't forget to `plus` and mark my post as `answer`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183504/discussion-between-poobear-and-andre-ds).